# Get labelField text and form field values together

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs, extjs5

I intend to build a text with the text of labelField and textfield value

In my fiddle example the text of the fieldLabel is created dynamically.

what I want to achieve is to generate a text with the text of fielLabel and the value of the textfield.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1icj

As is the fiddle displays **"Homer, Simpson"**

What I want to achieve: **"Name Homer, Last Name Simpson"**

It seems to me there is no method which gives the value of fieldLabel.

How to achieve this?

It is possible in some way, using binding?

What if I use a custom property, it is possible to obtain its value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
buttons: [{
        text: 'GetValues',
        handler: function() {
            var formValues = this.up('form').getForm().getValues();
            console.log(formValues);

            var finalValues = [];
            var needsLineBreak = false;

            if (formValues != null) {
                var form=this.up('form'),
                    index=0;
                Ext.iterate(formValues,function(key,val){
                    finalValues += form.getComponent(index).getFieldLabel()+':';
                    finalValues += val + ',';
                    index++;
                });   
              finalValues=finalValues.slice(finalValues.lenght,-1);
            }
             console.log(finalValues);
        }
    }],
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.George. Works great. I edited my fiddle with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can use getter/setter to achieve this functionality

```
items: [{
    fieldLabel: labelName,
    name: 'first',
    get value(){
        return this.fieldLabel +' Homer';
    },
    allowBlank: false,

    myCustomProp: labelName

},{
    fieldLabel: labelLastName,
    name: 'last',
    get value(){
        return this.fieldLabel +' Simpson';
    },
    allowBlank: false
}],
```

Comment: why add other functions if form as getValues? why this sintax? why the value should be save in object like custom property?

Comment: Thanks nathanel for help.